# iText7. Filling out PDF form is not working as expected

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I was about to use iTextSharp to fill out PDF form, when I've found out, that there is new kid on the block: iText 7.0. Naturally I gave it a try and... it didn't go well, unfortunately. Here is an issue. I have editable PDF form, that's need to be filled out programmatically. I used following code to acomplished that:

```
string srcPdfFormPath = @"<Path to source pdf form>";
string destPdfFormPath = @"<Path to destination pdf form>";
using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(destPdfFormPath)))
{
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);

    var fieldName = "FullName";
    var pdfField = form.GetField(fieldName);
    if (pdfField != null)
        pdfField.SetValue("John Doe", null);
    else
        Debug.WriteLine($"Cannot find following field {fieldName } on pdf form.");

    pdfDocument.Close();
}
```

Though desired field has been populated, the form not only has been flattened(which, AFAIK is not expected behavior), but also when populated pdf would be opened in Acrobat reader it would produce following message:

> "This document enabled extended features in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.
>   The document has been changed since it was created and use of extended
>   features is no longer available. Please contact the author for the
>   original version of this document."

Those results are not what we have been shooting for. So in order to preserve the document editability and get rid of pesky message I've decided to open PDF form in "Append Mode". Here is a code I've used:

```
string srcPdfFormPath = @"<Path to source pdf form>";
string destPdfFormPath = @"<Path to destination pdf form>";
using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(destPdfFormPath)
                         , new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode()))
{
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);

    var fieldName = "FullName";
    var pdfField = form.GetField(fieldName);
    if (pdfField != null)
        pdfField.SetValue("John Doe", null);
    else
        Debug.WriteLine($"Cannot find following field {fieldName } on pdf form.");

    pdfDocument.Close();
}
```

And, alas, this attempt also failed on its mission. Though pesky message would no longer be seen, the form itself would not be populated, which is not acceptable. And for the life of me I could not figure out why those behaviors are persist and go together, like horse and carriage!

So question is: what am I missing here? Is there way to make it work using new version of iText?

Comment: Maybe your form is a hybrid form, containing AcroForm technology and XFA. As XFA will be deprecated in PDF 2.0 (ISO-32000-2), we decided not to implement it in iText 7.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Is there way to check that?

Comment: The form not being filled in in append mode is a known bug in iText7 atm, we are working on solving it.

Comment: @SamuelHuylebroeck Thank you sir for the info. Is it possible to follow the progress? I would like to give it a try when bug would be fixed.

Comment: It will probably get fixed by next release (7.0.2), but we currently do not have a timetable for it, since 7.0.1's release was recent.

Comment: @SamuelHuylebroeck I see. Thank you for the response!

Comment: We might publish a NuGet feed with daily snapshots. They are **NOT RECOMMENDED FOR PRODUCTION USE** -> This means, if it blows up in your face or eats your firstborn child, don't blame us, but you'll be able to try it out before the release. We've had snapshot builds for years with the Java version. Follow our Twitter feed to know when and where that NuGet feed is available.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse U mad my day!:))))) I swear on my firstborn child, that I would neither use it(daily feed) in prod, nor blaming you.:))

Comment: I've pulled the latest iText 7 (.NET) code and can see that the append mode bug has been fixed.  There still seems to be an issue with populating the value of a dropdown field (in append mode), e.g. "Gender" dropdown with "Male" and "Female" values.  I did confirm that it worked without append mode (PDF created with Acrobat DC 2015.020.20039).

Comment: @JC1001 Thank you u for the update. I'll take a look on new version.